# Is it possible to get the thread information using python?

Tags: python, multithreading, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-monitoring

I'm working on the system monitor using python. I want to know that is it possible to get the information of the processes thread using python like thread_id, thread_name, memory consumed by that particular thread.

I used the python psutil library and it's just given the Thread_id, kernel_time and the user_time of the thread. I want name and the memory consumption as well.

Comment: Threads don't have memory consumption - the entire process space is available to the thread. Besides thread local data which is usually small, there is nothing associated with the thread itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.